# Cannot setTextColor if using ButterKnife?

Tags: android, animation, butterknife

I have this code using ButterKnife:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.mainAct_OKBtnTv) TextView mTextView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.black));
    }
```

This return the Null Exception.
However, when I try the findViewById()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView mTextView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainAct_OKBtnTv);
        mTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.black));
    }
```

The setTextColor method now is successful.
I figured out the problem is I "try to find the text views before telling android which xml file to inflate". My question is: Is there anyway to use the ButterKnife with setTextColor?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize ButterKnife after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` Use 
`ButterKnife.bind(this);` See [official](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) Javadoc

Comment: Thank your. OMG I forgot this basic bind(this).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you must call the ButterKnife.bind method in your onCreate() method:

```
  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    // TODO Use fields...
  }
```